# Preference > Install/Update > Availabe Software Site prob

Tags: android, eclipse, preference

I made two simple application and they're working well, but when I run my application now, it gives me an error, I went to help >> Check for updates, it gives me an error that says "jar:file:/F:/Learn eclipse/SDK/SDK/sdk/platforms/android 2.2/android.jar" I tried to change it from "Preference > Install/Update > Available Software Site" but it aims right! I have the SDK somewhere else which isn't connected to what I'm working to, so the direction is correct, even at "Windows >> Android SDK Manager" it's written on the top left "F:\Learn>SDK\SDK\sdk"" so everything is right! Does anyone know what's wrong with "jar:file:/F:/Learn eclipse/SDK/SDK/sdk/platforms/android 2.2/android.jar"? or goes anyone know what to write in "Help > Install New Software"? "I talk too much, sorry"

Comment: It is a question or a 'mess-tion' ?

Comment: The question is.. "jar:file:/F:/Learn eclipse/SDK/SDK/sdk/platforms/android 2.2/android.jar" not working. why?

Comment: Or why http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/froyo is not working in "Help > Install New Software"?

Comment: you need to format your question first!! add spacing, new line and make it more readable!!

Comment: Ok,.  Why download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/froyo in not working anymore in "Help > Install New Software"?

Comment: Do I have line them? :)